# Best way to emulate older browser renderings in CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What's the best way to go about simulating how a current page would render in an older browser dynamically using CSS/JS? (A slider with say -- Mozilla Phoenix, IE 3, Navigator, etc.) This wouldn't be for testing purposes, of which there are many solutions (browsershots and the like), but rather for demonstration purposes so people could get a feel for what the current page would look like if rendered with an older browser.

Comment: I don't think there is a sane way to do this. You would have to *recreate* old rendering bugs. Apart from being extremely cumbersome, it would also be a terrible job to have to do.

Comment: Probably not doable, unless you painstakingly recreated the rendering differences with custom CSS code by comparing it to a screenshot of the actual rendering.. at which point, it would have been simpler to just show them the screenshots.

Comment: Why would anyone care what their site looks like in *IE 3*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that you could reliably do that with just CSS/JS alone. However, if you were just going to show this to a client, you could screenshot the browsershots and then use CSS/JS to switch them out with a slider?

Comment: At this point I'm just thinking of faking it by making some CSS that would emulate what a browsershots screenshot looks like for an older browser, even if it isn't perfect. I was just curious if there was a better way.